# Scipy minimize erroring for large array of variables

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, optimization

Hi I am trying to use scipy for optimization. The minimize function with method as 'COBYLA' is working fine for small array size but errors out for larger sized arrays. I tried with 'COBYLA' and 'SLSQP' methods since I have a constrained optimization problem for non-linear functions.

Code snippet:

```
import scipy as sp
import random

def mytest7obj(x, x_d, y_d, z_d, power):
    for x_i in x:
        if x_i < 0:
            return 0.
    sum = 0.
    for i in range(x_d):
        for j in range(z_d):
            term = 1.
            for k in range(y_d):
                term *= (x[i*(y_d*z_d)+j*(y_d)+k] ** power[k])
            sum += term
    return 0. - sum
def mytest7():
    x_d = 30
    y_d = 10
    z_d = 100
    goal = 1000000.
    constraints = []
    power = []
    for i in range(y_d):
        power.append(random.uniform(0.,0.3))
    constraints.append({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: goal - sum(x)})
    print 'power: %s\n' % (power,)
    result = sp.optimize.minimize(fun = mytest7obj, x0 = [30.] * (x_d*y_d*z_d), method = 'COBYLA', args = (x_d, y_d, z_d, power), jac=False, constraints=constraints, options={'disp':True, 'rhobeg':3., 'maxiter': 10000})
    print 'goal attained: %s'% (sum(result.x),)

if __name__ == “__main__”:
    mytest7()
```

The traceback of the error with method 'COBYLA' is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opt_test.py", line 584, in <module>
    print 'mytest7'; mytest7()
  File "opt_test.py", line 571, in mytest7
    result = sp.optimize.minimize(fun = mytest7obj, x0 = [30.] * (x_d*y_d*z_d), method = 'COBYLA', args = (x_d, y_d, z_d, power), jac=False, constraints=constraints, options={'disp':True, 'rhobeg':3., 'maxiter': 10000})
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 385, in minimize
    return _minimize_cobyla(fun, x0, args, constraints, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/cobyla.py", line 238, in _minimize_cobyla
    dinfo=info)
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (-1594577286,)
```

With 'SLSQP', the error is:

```
File "opt_test.py", line 586, in <module>
    print 'test'; test()
  File "opt_test.py", line 454, in test
    x = get_optimal(base, budget, initial_values, x_elas, y_elas, x_history, y_history, constraint_coeffs, opt_method = 'SLSQP')
  File "opt_test.py", line 355, in get_optimal
    constraints=constraints, options=opts)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 388, in minimize
    constraints, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 316, in _minimize_slsqp
    w = zeros(len_w)
MemoryError
```

I am using python 2.7.5, 
scipy version: 0.14.0rc1, 
numpy version: 1.8.1

Comment: ``x[i*(y_d*z_d)+j*(y_d)+k]`` does not look right - if I skimmed through your correctly, the ``minimize()`` minimizes for a 1d array (because of the parameter x0).